# Hide outline on pseudo-element only

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to absolute position an arrow relative to a button that toggles a filter box using `:before` pseudo-element.

I think I **can't** position relative to the filter box because its width is related to other div and I need the triangle to be aligned with the outside button.

**Problem:** when button is focused, the outline is present both in button and its `:before`, aka my triangle. I'm searching for a solution that outlines the button, but not its `:before`.

**What I've already tried:** set the rule `outline: none;` in the `:before` selector. Didn't worked.

**What I've achieved:**
[image: What I've achieved...]

**My code, simplified for question purpose:**

```js
/* Toggle control isn't necessary for the purpose of the question */
```

```css
.button-filter {
  background-color: #333;
  color: $click-white;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
}
.button-filter:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 15px);
  bottom: -20px;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #333;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<button class="button-filter" autofocus>Filter</button>
```

Comment: Is this really a outline? Looks more like a border or a box-shadow instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `outline` with a `box-shadow`to avoid this effect:

```css
.button-filter {
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
}
.button-filter:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 15px);
  bottom: -20px;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #333;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
}

.button-filter:focus {
  outline:none;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px blue;
}
```

```html
<button class="button-filter" autofocus>Filter</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Asuming that the pseudo will used to create an arrow next to another element, you don't really need it to be a triangle, it can be a rotated square. The lower part of it will be hidden by the other div.

If this is the case, the you can set the pseudo as a small square located inside the button. I set it red to show where it is, but in production you can set background transparent, or set z-index : -1;

And then set a shadow, located where you want the triangle to be. Since this is a shadow, not a real element, the outline won't be applied to it. (Note: the element is rotated, so the shadow coordinates are tricky)

```js
/* Toggle control isn't necessary for the purpose of the question */
```

```css
.button-filter {
  background-color: #333;
  color: $click-white;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
}

.button-filter:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 40px 40px 0px 10px black;
}
```

```html
<button class="button-filter" autofocus>Filter</button>
```